# UPDATE one column of multiple tables at once

Tags: mysql, performance, multiple-tables

Here is my code:

```
UPDATE
tb_character_name t1, tb_character_area_crime t2, tb_character_friend t3,
tb_character_addr t4, tb_character_parents t5, tb_character_gps t6,
tb_character_image t7, tb_character_info t8, tb_character_data t9
SET
t1.item_deleted = 1, t2.item_deleted = 1, t3.item_deleted = 1,
t4.item_deleted = 1, t5.item_deleted = 1, t6.item_deleted = 1,
t7.item_deleted = 1, t8.item_deleted = 1, t9.item_deleted = 1
WHERE
t1.id_character = '123456' AND t2.id_character = t1.id_character AND t3.id_character = t2.id_character AND
t4.id_character = t3.id_character AND t5.id_character = t4.id_character AND t6.id_character = t5.id_character AND
t7.id_character = t6.id_character AND t8.id_character = t7.id_character AND t9.id_character = t8.id_character;
```

This code runs normally but the columns (item_deleted) didn't change to 1. I don't want to call 9 mysql queries because I know its CPU expensive. Whats wrong with this code?

Comment: It is not a given that one update joining 9 tables will be "cheaper" than 9 much simpler updates; I'd actually be surprised if this monstrosity was more efficient in any way. My guess as to what is wrong is that one of those 9 tables does not have an id_character field with the specified value.

Comment: I tried changing the operator AND to OR but it made no difference. And, yes, all the tables have id_character field set to 0

Comment: If they are all id_character = 0, why would you expect a query with `WHERE id_character = '123456'` to affect any of them? ...and OR would even be more disastrous. To be clear, your query does not express an attempt to update those tables in parallel, it is a 9 table join.

Comment: Sorry, I meant all them have id_character set to '123456' and item_deleted set to 0. If one of them wouldnt have these fields, mysql should log an error. Am I wrong?

Comment: If one or more of those tables lacks the field completely, you'll have an error; but if it is just that they all have the field and one or more lacks the presence of that value, then there will be no error and none will update.

Comment: Well I really need to have those tables fields in 9 separate tables. Would you call my query or 9 queries to perform such task?

Comment: 9 simple separate queries. As long as id_character is indexed in each table the simpler queries should be fast; I'd not be surprised if all 9 were faster than a working version of yours. Keep in mind that they are technically not the same operation as yours. Yours is currently "mark rows with the specified field value as deleted in these tables if and only if each and every table has at least one row with that field value".

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually my script calls all 9 queries using mysqli_multi_query(), and all id_character are indexed (BIGINT). Thankyou for your tips.

Comment: I'll put a final answer so the question can be marked accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update columns across multiple tables using various JOIN methods, and those columns can have matching names as long as you specify which table for each such field (in fact you are required to in the case of such ambiguities. **However, for large numbers of tables all using identical criteria separate queries are likely faster, more stable/predictable, and more coherent.**